# How to pass data between views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-views

I am working on a MVC 4 project.

What I want is that when user clicks on a button or a checkbox whatever on a view A, this calls a **javascript function**, the function in the view A **passes some data to a controller**, and then the controller opens a view B, when the user does something on view B and clicks a OK button, **View B passes data to view A and View B closes**.

Is is possible to achieve that? If yes, how to do it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: you can use `Temp Data` to pass data between views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, its definitely possible. You can use JQuery async calls to your MVC controller and have it return a partial view. You can use a DIV to house partial-view A and partial-view B, clearing the DIVs contents before adding the HTML from your most recent result.